# Replication / sync SQL Server [MDF] database to CE database [SDF]

Tags: sql-server-2008, database-replication

I have two database in SQL Server - one on a server-version as a `MDF/LDF` file and one CE database (`SDF` file) with the same structure ..

I'm required to do sync/replicate between these two databases .. is this scenario possible ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is definitely possible... there is a framework for this kind of stuff from MS - see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb726002.aspx

EDIT:

Another option though not as flexible would be to use replication... for details see http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171850%28v=sql.100%29.aspx

Comment: Its like a one time replication not "much" often